# How to get Serial number or Mac address of Airprint printer from iOS application programatically

Tags: ios, printing, airprint

I implemented printing functionality in my iOS app. My iPad is connected to AirPrint Printer on same wi-fi. Is it possible to get Serial number or Mac address of printer in iOS application before giving print command?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two stage approach:

1. Query for the IP address of the printer, using standard Bonjour methods.
2. Find the MAC address of the printer using `arp`.

I cannot provide you the code... but the command line utility `dns-sd` will do to demo the first step.

Whatever info this command line can return to you, the dns-sd library API can also do. See *`/usr/include/dns_sd.h`* for more details....

The following outlines the steps to follow for the first stage.

### 1a.

Assuming that you want to find out the instance names for all AirPrint-capable devices in domain `dns-sd.org.`...

You'd then use:

```
dns-sd  -B  _ipp._tcp.,_universal dns-sd.org.

  Browsing for _ipp._tcp.,_universal.dns-sd.org.
  DATE: ---Sat 02 Jul 2016---
  14:20:07.190  ...STARTING...
  Timestamp     A/R  Flags if Domain       Service Type  Instance Name
  14:20:07.626  Add      2  0 dns-sd.org.  _ipp._tcp.    Stuart's Home AirPrint Printer
  ^C
```

(Note the `,_universal` suffix [requesting the AirPrint subset] to the standard query of `_ipp._tcp.` which requests the list of all generic IPP-capable print devices...)

You've now found one instance with the name *"Stuart's Home AirPrint Printer"*.

### 1b.

You can now query for the hostname of the network node which is hosting service instance *"Stuart's Home AirPrint Printer"*:

```
dns-sd  -L  "Stuart's Home AirPrint Printer"  _ipp._tcp.  dns-sd.org.

  Lookup Stuart's Home AirPrint Printer._ipp._tcp..dns-sd.org.
  DATE: ---Sat 02 Jul 2016---
  14:37:44.436  ...STARTING...
  14:37:44.813  Stuart's\032Home\032AirPrint\032Printer._ipp._tcp.dns-sd.org. can be reached at airprint.dns-sd.org.:631 (interface 0)
     txtvers=1                                             \
     qtotal=1                                              \
     pdl=application/postscript,application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.hp-PCLXL,application/pdf,image/urf \
     rp=ipp/printer                                        \
     URF=CP99,W8,OB10,PQ3-4-5,ADOBERGB24,DEVRGB24,DEVW8,SRGB24,IS1-2-4,MT1-2-3-5-12,MT1-2-3-5-12,RS600 \
     ty=HP\ LaserJet\ 400\ color\ M451nw                   \
     product=\(HP\ LaserJet\ 400\ color\ M451nw\)          \
     priority=10                                           \
     adminurl=http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html \
     note=At\ Stuart\'s\ house                             \
     Color=T                                               \
     Duplex=F                                              \
     Scan=F
  ^C
```

Note the line *"...can be reached at airprint.dns-sd.org.:631"*. This gives you the hostname you are looking for.

### 1c.

You can now ask for the IP addresses (IPv4 as well as IPv6) where this AirPrint instance is hosted:

```
dns-sd -Gv4v6 airprint.dns-sd.org. 

  DATE: ---Sat 02 Jul 2016---
  14:19:12.040  ...STARTING...
  Timestamp     A/R Flags if Hostname               Address                                   TTL
  14:19:12.426  Add     2  0 airprint.dns-sd.org.   50.197.138.101                            75
  14:19:12.544  Add     2  0 airprint.dns-sd.org.   0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000%  77   No Such Record
  ^C
```

So this AirPrinter does have an IPv4 (*50.197.138.101*) but no IPv6 address.

### 2.

To find the respective MAC address, just use ARP.